# How i make a div change position to fit screen

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div working as a PopUP when user click in an area.

The thing is depending on what corner the user click the div should appear in different position so doesn't hide any part of the content.

> Content Area 
>   A   B 
>   C   D

So if user click on A corner div should appear right and bottom
So if user click on B corner div should appear left and bottom
So if user click on C corner div should appear right and top
So if user click on D corner div should appear left and top

Normal click show C Format, but should change if the div won't fit on the screen

I have the x,y from user click and also have div and content area size so I can calculate when normal format wont fit on the content.

I'm new with CSS.
My idea is i should have 4 styles {A,B,C,D} 
and my javascript function will calculate wich is the appropiate class and change it before appear.

**So what attributes should I configure to styles {A,B,C,D} to acomplish this?**

```
#container{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.box{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;    
}
```

PD: Of course this is my idea of how solve it, but I'm also open to suggestions.

Comment: im sorry but i fail to see a question in your question.

Comment: Last line before the PD. How i set A,B,C,D styles

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Done, with this style the x,y is on the TOP, LEFT corner of the box. I need the x,y be on the other 3 corners too.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan *"depending on what corner the user click the div should appear in different position"*. seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza can you please show your HTML sample and the JS you have currently?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I got my final result thanks. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

When you click the div move the top,left corner to x,y,
if the content will land outside the container, the corner change.

```js
var theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");
 
container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

function getClickPosition(e) {
    var parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);  
    
    var xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x ;
    if (xPosition + theThing.clientWidth > contentContainer.clientWidth)
    {
        xPosition = xPosition - theThing.clientWidth;
    }
    var yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y ;
    if (yPosition + theThing.clientHeight > contentContainer.clientHeight)
    {
        yPosition = yPosition - theThing.clientHeight;
    }
    theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
    theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}
 
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;
      
    while (element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#contentContainer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#thing {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="thing">Hola<br> World</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is quite simply. as trivial as it sounds:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
.top_left_green{
    background:green;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.top_right_red{
    background:red;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
.bottom_left_blue{
    background:blue;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.bottom_right_yellow{
    background:yellow;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_left_green"></div>
<div class="top_right_red"></div>
<div class="bottom_left_blue"></div>
<div class="bottom_right_yellow"></div>
```

Comment: The question is indecipherable, what's that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan its actually spelled "indecipherable", but whatever floats your boat mate.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza there is a "insert code snippet" button

Comment: I see what you did and give me an idea. If user click on X,Y on the SouthWest corner of the blue box. I calculate a new x1,y1 above that area then change css  LEFT, TOP value to x1, y1+div.height so the div appear complete. So i don't need 4 styles, only one and change the LEFT, TOP on the click event.

Comment: yep. the point of my answer was to show you that you can use the `left/top/right/bottom` in css combined with `position:absolute` to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: can the downvoter please explain the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Thanks Banana, you can look my final solution.

Comment: yes i saw. i actually was going to post [This](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/krf2x9u7/) but it seems its not needed anymore :)